# compare two attribute of objects from different list of object python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, operators

I'm still pretty new to python and oop and I have some struggles resolving this problem without breaking the performance.

I want to compare the id of my user (that's what I have done with the **eq** function) and if the id is equal I want to know if their time attribute is greater than the other user who the id is the same

I retrieve my user from a different source, that's why I have to compare them.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self,id: str, time: int) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.time = time

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return self.id == __o.id

list_user= [User(1, 20),User(2, 20),User(3, 45),...]
list_user2=[User(1, 5),User(4323, 20),User(3, 60),...]

for user in list_user:
        if user.id in list_user2 and user.time > list_user2:
            do_something()
        else:
            continue
```

Can I retrieve the user that matches the user in user_list2 in the first condition to compare their times attribute?

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can we assume that the ids in each list are unique (unique within its list)?

Comment: yes, every id is unique within its list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, _id: str, time: int) -> None:
        self.id = _id
        self.time = time


list_user = [User(1, 20), User(2, 20), User(3, 45), ...]
list_user2 = [User(1, 5), User(4323, 20), User(3, 60), ...]

list_user2_ids = [u.id for u in list_user2]

for user in list_user:
    try:
        identical_user = list_user2[list_user2_ids.index(user.id)]
        if user.time > identical_user.time:
            do_something()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: @bakelue did you try to time this solution ?

Comment: how do you call this kind of alghoritm approach ?? its really  fast compared to a for i in list1 if/if by at least 20times by my tests ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User:

    def __init__(self,id: str, time: int) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.time = time

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return self.id == __o.id


User(1, 20)
list_user = [User(1, 20), User(2, 20), User(3, 45)]
list_user2 = [User(1, 5), User(4323, 20), User(3, 60)]

for user in list_user:
    if user in list_user2:
        if user.time>list_user2[list_user2.index(user)].time:
            print(f"list1's user {user.id} time is bigger")
        else:
            print(f"list2's user {user.id} time is bigger")
    else:
        print("not found")
```

In line 17 I've just use the index of the first list's user to get the time value of the second lists user with the same id, then just compared it
**OUTPUT**

```
list1's user 1 time is bigger
not found
list2's user 3 time is bigger
```

Comment: Yours solution work, but it's pretty slow, it take me 340s for 13240 match in the lists.
I don't know where the slowdown occur

Comment: Its probably in the the index retrieval in the 2nd if check.

Answer (score 0):

modifying `__eq__` , not sure it is orthodox:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, _id: str, time: int) -> None:
        self.id = _id
        self.time = time
        
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return self.id == __o.id and self.time > __o.time

list_user = [User(1, 20), User(2, 20), User(3, 45), User(4,99)]
list_user2 = [User(1, 5), User(4323, 20), User(3, 60), User(4,98)]

for user in list_user:
        print(user)
        if user in list_user2:
                print('OK ' ,user.id)
        else:
            print('pass')
            pass
```

output:

```
<__main__.User object at 0x7fafc54554c0>
OK  1
<__main__.User object at 0x7fafc52ff130>
pass
<__main__.User object at 0x7fafc52ff220>
pass
<__main__.User object at 0x7fafc52ff370>
OK  4
>
```

Comment: @bakelue did you try to time this solution ?